# How do convert an enum int value to a string in ionic template

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-filter

I have a template in AngularJS that has the following content

```
<li>{{item.Day }},{{item.Time}},{{item.Notes}}</li>
```

Problem is that `item.Day` is an int from `0` to `6`, representing the javascript `Date` equivalent for a day, i.e. `0=Sunday, 1= Monday...6=Saturday`.

Now I would like by view to show `Sun`, `Mon`..etc.. rather than `1,2,3` etc..

How can I do that in ionic?

I am using `linq-js` to generate the data, however I'm not sure how to convert it there so I'm open to a solution in the controller, but ideally in the template view.

For completeness, controller code is here:

```
var data = $linq(allMassTimesData); // get mass times of just this church..
          var val =  data.where("x => x.ShopID == " + selectedShopID )
            .orderBy(function (x) {
              return x.Day;
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't You just use it like this, First create a array object for days in string like

`$scope.days=['Sun','Mon','tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','Sat'];`

Then in your template just use

```
<li>{{days[item.Day]}},{{item.Time}},{{item.Notes}}</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks -that's a great solution. very easy :)